# GitHub API: Personal access token removes itself

Tags: github, token, access-token, github-api

I need an access to Github GraphQL API in order to permanently make the following request each N hours:

```
query($ids: [ID!]!) {
rateLimit {
    cost
    remaining
    resetAt
}

nodes(ids: $ids) {
    ... on Repository {
        milestones(last: 100) {
            nodes {
                issues(last: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        closedAt
                        closed
                    }
                }

                state
                dueOn
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

1. I create a personal access token [like it is said here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#authenticating-with-graphql) with only 1 scope: *public_repo*.
2. I copy and paste it to my application properties.
3. I launch my application, it is working as expected.
4. But sometimes, under some unclear circumstances, almost randomly (during app execution or after shut down), Github API responses with *401 Unauthorized*.
5. I visit my Settings / Developer settings / Personal access tokens. Last created token disappears.
6. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Probably you commit the token to your GitHub repo. if its the case Github will remove the token immediately. so you need to set your token as a variable environment in your system.

Comment: How does one set the token as a variable environment? Is it by using .env?